# Regex to replace a char, but only the first if more than one

Tags: regex

Would like to replace all of a char, but only the first occurrence if it is followed by any number of the char.

Example:

```
This_is__a___Test

Replace _ with *

This*is*_a*__Test
```

Doing it in Scala, but any language would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!_)_
```

This matches an underscore not preceded by another underscore. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rM9bX0/1).

Comment: Cool! Thanks, that worked perfect.  Had not used a negative lookbehind before - sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I did this for exercise in Javascript in case someone else comes by it.

```
"This_is__a___Test".replace(/_+/g, function (match) {
  return '*' + match.slice(1);
});
```